# How to determine array length of uint8_t?

Tags: c, arrays, strlen, uint8t

I'm trying to determine array length of `msg` on the below code. I used `strlen` and `sizeof` but they don't return 6. What function can I use to determine the length of `uint8_t` array or how can I modify the below code (`osal_DataLenght()` func)?

```
int osal_DataLength( char *pString ){
  return (int)( strlen( pString ) );
}

void setNewLevel( uint8_t newLevel ){ //GW specific
  uint8_t msg[8] = {'\0'};
  msg[0] = '0';
  msg[1] = '7';
  msg[6]= newLevel;
  //msg[7] = '0';
  printf("the array length:%d\n", osal_DataLength(msg) );
}

int main(void){
    setNewLevel(0xD5);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't need msg[7] for now, if I have to use it to find the length, then I can uncomment it

Comment: The length of `msg` *is* 8, whether you initialize all the elements or not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To know the size of your array, write (in **`setNewLevel()`** as said @Dabo) :

```
sizeof(msg)/sizeof(uint8_t);
```

`strlen()` returns the size of a string (char array terminated by `NULL`, ie `'\0'`). You CAN'T use it in this context, since :

1. `msg[2]` to `msg[5]` values are not initialized
2. `msg` is not a `char` sequence terminated by `NULL`.

Comment: I want to find out length of the array, not the size of the array

Comment: There is no such thing in C.

Comment: @sven : what do you mean ? This ratio gives the length of your array (like `.length` in Javascript).

Comment: Amessihel, I don't know Javascript but I guess something similar is what I want. However, I want to find out if it is possible to do it even the mid elements are '\0'

Comment: @sven So use the sizeof solution, but only in the block where the array is defined. Otherwise define a `struct` with a `size_t` member which stores the size.

Comment: `msg[2]` to `msg[5]` are initialized to `0`, which equals to `'\0'`.

Answer (score 1):

When passing array to a function it decays to a pointer, and there is no way in function to know the length of your original array. Pass the length as additional variable

```
int osal_DataLength( char *pString, int size )
. 
.
.
printf("the array length:%d\n", osal_DataLength(msg, sizeof(msg)) );
```

Answer (score 0):

```
strlen(const char *str)
```

Strlen function is looking for '\0' to finish and show array length. So you are doing all array datas firstly '\0' then in your setNewLevel function msg[0]= 0 and msg[1] = 7 and then msg[6] = newLevel but others are '\0' so you are always see length is 2 .

Comment: Do I need to arbitrary assign values to the 2nd, 3rd,4th, and 5th elements of the array in order to detect the length of the array is 7 on the above code?

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use it like this. Firstly you can use **memset** to set all element arrays to **ZERO"0"** then you add what you want in array. You have to do last thing in array element you use **'\0'**. if you are use like that you can see array length.

```
    void setNewLevel( uint8_t newLevel ){ //GW specific
    uint8_t msg[8] = {'\0'};
    memset(msg,'0',8); //  to set all element to zero 
    msg[0] = '0';
    msg[1] = '7';
    msg[6]= newLevel;
    msg[7]= '\0';  // this is array's last element.
    printf("the array length:%d\n", osal_DataLength(msg) );
    }
```

Comment: `uint8_t msg[8] = {'\0'};` sets first element to `'\0'` and the rest to `0`, so `memset()` is redundant.